# Extra Space In The "Div" And Around It

Tags: html, css

For some reason, there is some extra space around the navigation bar and in it. I have set the margins and padding all to 0px, so there should be no space around it, and I don't know how to remove the extra space in the div. I have tried looking it up, but I haven't been able to find anything that helps, so I hoped that some of you could, Thanks!

```css
* {
    margin: auto 0;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a {
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav1 {
    height: 10fr;
    width: auto;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background: #787878;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto);
    font-size: 23px;
}

.left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.left:hover {
    background: #404040;
    border-radius: 13px;
}

.right {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.right:hover {
    background: #404040;
    border-radius: 13px;
}

.disable {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav1">
        <ul class="header">
            <li class="left disable">Home Page</a></li>
            <li class="left"><a href="">Find Support</a></li>
            <li class="left"><a href="">Want To Offer Support?</a></li>
            <li class="left"><a href="">Found A Mistake?</a></li>
            <li class="right"><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which div??????

Comment: In case if you are looking to have same height for all li items . you can refer this example..
https://jsbin.com/wopegisixo/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class `nav1` there is a white border. Remove it.

```
.nav1 {
    height: 10fr;
    width: auto;
    //border: 2px solid white;
    background: #787878;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Other solution has written by `HanJeaHwan`

Comment: Oh yeh, sorry, just realised that I had left that over from a previous design, thanks for being so quick!

Answer (score 1):

set `margin-bottom: 0` for header class

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto);
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for being so quick!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by adding the `margin-bottom: 0` code inside the ul tag.

as follows

```css
    * {
        margin: auto 0;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    }
    
    li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 20px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    a {
        color: white;
    }
    
    a:hover {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .nav1 {
        height: 10fr;
        width: auto;
        border: 2px solid white;
        background: #787878;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
    
    .header {
        display: flex;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(auto auto auto);
        font-size: 23px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    .left {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .left:hover {
        background: #404040;
        border-radius: 13px;
    }
    
    .right {
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    
    .right:hover {
        background: #404040;
        border-radius: 13px;
    }
    
    .disable {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
 
<body>
    <nav class="nav1">
        <ul class="header">
            <li class="left disable">Home Page</a>
            </li>
            <li class="left"><a href="">Find Support</a></li>
            <li class="left"><a href="">Want To Offer Support?</a></li>
            <li class="left"><a href="">Found A Mistake?</a></li>
            <li class="right"><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```